# DateFormat Conversion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string that is in this format:

```
2012-11-08T13:50:05.284-08:00
```

I need to convert it into this format:

```
November 8, 2012 1:50 PM,
```

I have identified the pattern of the date to YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD, like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD"];   
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-11-08T13:50:05.284-08:00"];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *newDateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong here? 
Is the format template correct or not?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is the value in newDateStr after the last line?

Comment: You've already screwed up with the date format.  Use yyyy, not YYYY, and dd, not DD.  And ... screw it, just look at [the standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ" would be my first cut.

Comment: And don't forget to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX" (for the first conversion, but not the second).

Comment: (This is definitely a duplicate question, but I'm too lazy to look up a prior one.)

Comment: @HotLicks, you should post your comments as the answer so I mark up.

Comment: @HotLicks Tried the template you gave (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ) it does not work!

Comment: @HetalVora both date and newDateStr are null as the dateformat failed to convert the string

Comment: If testing on a device, make sure that the device locale and the 12/24 setting in "settings" are in agreement.  Setting 12 hour time in London will muck things up, eg.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:As I getting valid output.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'-'S':'S"];

 NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-11-08T13:50:05.250-8:00"];

 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];

 NSString *newDateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

 NSLog(@"newDateStr is %@", newDateStr);
```

Comment: Tried this but got null for both newDateStr and date again!

Comment: Hey @Mr.Anonymous please copy and paste the code.I am using the above code and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I tried this code and it worked fine for me. @Mr. Anonymous -What is your device timezone set to?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. using `'-'S':'S` for the timezone is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this just ( just remove last 5 characters from the string )

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012-11-08T13:50:05.284"];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
    NSString *newDateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```